# Javascript Mp3 Player, NONE FLASH

Tags: javascript, jquery, mp3

I currently have a simple flash Mp3 player on my site which works lovely. The issue is, most cell phones do not support flash and a large portion of my visitors come through via a mobile device. The alternative to this is to replace the flash player with a javascript player. I found a JQuery one but it only works on HTML5 compatible browsers. Does anyone know of a good alternative that would work on mobile devices as well as most desktop web browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the browser supports the HTML5 [audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp) if not, use the flash version.

Comment: Mobile devices do not support either

Comment: @Yo, many mobile browsers/engines do, including mobile WebKit and mobile Gecko, which is a huge swath of mobile devices being sold now.

Comment: @Yo: But if by *mobile browsers* you mean Opera Mini... Then you're right. No Javascript, no HTML5 and no Flash either...

Answer (score 3):

Check out [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/).