# play video and audio using html5?

Tags: html, audio, video

I'm developing site in my site I need to play audio and video support all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you can't use 1 video format for all browsers.
I recommend you to take advance of putting the html5 video tag with multiple video sources, thus, depending on the browser, they will choose the supported format.

You can read more in:
http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/

It is really good and updated.

Answer (score 0):

[jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) looks good as well. Check this question too: [Javascript Mp3 Player, NONE FLASH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4591252/169534)